# Codeigniter - How to avoid template file for page

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, cron

I am working with Codeigniter and I have to add a cron file to run some scripts at backend. In Codeigniter if we create any page then we always have to add its template file like `$this->load->view('welcome_page', $data);`

But, I am working with cron file so I dose not need template file. So please let me know how I can avoid template file so my page will run like plan php page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you no need to load view file, just create function.
Remove,

```
$this->load->view('welcome_page', $data);
```

Comment: It works. You saved my lots of time. Thanks a lot :)